# Add this element to a Favourites array when the checkbox is clicked + post-Ajax element relationship

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`Food in foodslist` is printed out with ng-repeat. Each food has a checkbox.

I've written an ng-click function in the controller to add the food to array `favourites` when checked, and remove it if it's unchecked. This works. I then print `food in favourites` using the same template.

```
 $scope.toggleFavourite = function (food) {

   if (food.favourite === true) {
       $scope.favourites.push(food);
   } else if (food.favourite === false) {
       $scope.favourites.splice($scope.favourites.indexOf(food), 1);
   }
 }
```

Question 1: Is this the right place to put it/a good, "Angular" approach to solving this?

Question 2: I want to create a "perfect mirror" between items in the original list and items in the favourite list- all inputs that are changed on a Favourite are reflected on the original, and vice versa. But Favourites are not checked by default, even though "ng-checked" = " {{food.favourite}}", which equals "true" for Favourites.

How can I make sure this checkbox will always be checked for a food item in Favourites?

## [See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8jQjEomGByAjyzbtvM51?p=preview)

--

UPDATE

[In the first Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8jQjEomGByAjyzbtvM51?p=preview), the Favourites slider mirrors the original slider without me having to do any additional work- the `$$hashKey` portion of the element is still the same.

However in my actual implementation, the Food content is constantly reloaded through Ajax. Because the `$$hashKey` is different, the "connection" between the values of the elements is lost.

[Here's a 2nd Plunkr loading the content via Ajax so that the input values are not connected.](http://plnkr.co/edit/OcmcZ3sV3RpYfcExzxTE?p=preview)

I am looking for an efficient way to watch for a change in the inputs for the foods in both Favourites and Food, based on something stable (such as food.uid). If one instance of a food with uid = X has a value updated, the other will update to reflect this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not watch the whole of `Food` and `Favourites` for changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foodtemplate.html`, you have `ng-checked="{{ food.favourite }}"` for the favourites checkboxes instead of `ng-checked="food.favourite"`

I am not sure I understand the question in the update.

Comment: Thank you- this helped with the checkbox issue. I am trying to implement a $watch for changes, but I am having a hard time working from previous questions & fiddles. What I can't work out: if my $watch is in a directive, unrelated in the DOM or the $scope to the "food" model, how can I access that "food" model when $watch registers a change? I need to know which "food" has been changed so I can compare & track changes across the two sets. Here's a Plunkr that just prints "updated" when an input is changed: http://plnkr.co/edit/OcmcZ3sV3RpYfcExzxTE?p=preview